# no acceptable cc found in $PATH ... Already have working gcc

Tags: macos, gcc, terminal, configure

I am trying to install lesstif-0.93 onto my mac and i keep running into this error when i run configure:

```
bash-3.2$ ./configure
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for a BSD compatible install... ./install-sh -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for mawk... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... no
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking whether to build a Motif 1.2 compatible version... no
checking whether to build a Motif 2.0 compatible version... no
checking whether to build a Motif 2.1 compatible version... yes
checking whether to support EditRes... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl... no
configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH
bash-3.2$
```

I know that I have gcc because i compile lots of C sourse files everyday

also i did this:

```
bash-3.2$ whereis gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the build and host triples have `darwin11` (Lion), yet have the cpu `i386` rather than `x86_64`, suggests that the configure script is very old - which lesstif most certainly is. Maybe you'd have better luck with: `env CC=llvm-gcc ./configure`

Better yet: grab [lesstif-0.95.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lesstif/), and try that.

Comment: Ok now i am running into another problem

I was installing lesstif to get ddd debugger. Both installed ok


however when i try to open a file on ddd, this is what I am getting:

`bash-3.2$ ddd test
Error: No `Ddd' application defaults file
To resolve this problem, you can:

set the XAPPLRESDIR environment variable to the location of the file `Ddd', or
set the DDD_HOME environment variable to the location of `ddd/Ddd', or
install the `Ddd' file in the X application defaults directory, or
recompile DDD with builtin app-defaults file;
see the `--enable-builtin-app-defaults' option for details.`

Comment: tell me about it Brett. any ideas how to make it work??

I have X11 in my utilities folder

Comment: @sukhvir - do you _really_ need to use DDD? Presumably you have Xcode if you're using OSX. Much better tools. Or even command line gdb?

Comment: Brett as u can tell by my posts I am  noob when it comes to programming. I am a first year comp eng student. I can use gdb but DDD offers visual display debugging which is a lot easier and better when you are trying to run through 2000 lines of code. I HATE XCODE ... I had to go through shit lot of pain to install a simple GNU gcc on my mac osx lion as Xcode 4.3 doesn't come with it anymore.

I know its a pain but gcc is sorta requirement for my course and i would relly appreciate it if you could help me out.

Is there any specific commands i need to add to ./configure file while installingddd

Comment: @sukhvir - Just use the Xcode 4.3 llvm/clang compiler. Instead of `gcc`, use `clang`, or pass it to configure scripts with `CC=clang CXX=clang++`. If the code is portable, using `gcc` on other platforms should be fine. As for DDD, I haven't looked at it since the 90's, and I'm not able to help further.

Comment: P.S., Don't apologize for inexperience. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `config.log` (there's more than one) and search for the "checking for gcc" lines, and see what the error was.

If your GCC had a nonstandard name or install location then I'd suggest this:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc configure .....
```

but I'd be surprised if that was the trouble. You could try it anyway.

Comment: Thanks ams, that did the trick. However just for future reference could you please tell me why this didn't work:

export PATH=$HOME/my_gcc/bin:$PATH
./configure

It might sound stupid to you, but i am a noob at all this, I am a first year comp eng student

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to look in `config.log` to see. It might be that it only looks for `/usr/bin/gcc`?

Answer (score 0):

You have missing compiler C.
You can install e.g. gcc via the following command:

```
sudo brew install gcc47
```

If you don't have homebrew, please install it via:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```